# Oracle Selective Join

Tags: sql, oracle

My Table structure & data-

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
   (    EMP_ID NUMBER, 
    NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    SALARY NUMBER, 
    DEP_ID NUMBER, 
    ORG_ID NUMBER
   );

insert into employee values (1, 'Mark', 6000, 44, 5);
insert into employee values (2, 'John', 4000, 46, 5);
insert into employee values (2, 'John', 4500, 2, 5);
insert into employee values (3, 'Terry', 5000, 44, 5);
insert into employee values (4, 'Carol', 15000, 48, 5);
insert into employee values (4, 'Carol', 15500, 4, 5);
insert into employee values (5, 'Lewis', 18000, 46, 5);
```

```
CREATE TABLE DEPARTMENT
   (    DEP_ID NUMBER, 
    DEP_NAME VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
    ORG_ID NUMBER
   );

insert into DEPARTMENT values (null, 'NYD', 5);
insert into DEPARTMENT values (2, 'HR', 5);
insert into DEPARTMENT values (4, 'Analyst', 5);
```

In EMPLOYEE table, same employees can have 2 rows, one with a valid & other with an invalid DepartmentID.
Other employees simply have one entry with an invalid DepartmentID.

I want to join EMPLOYEE & DEPARTMENT table in such a way that, if an EMPLOYEE has 2 rows, then only the row with a valid DepartmentID should be selected.
If the EMPLOYEE has only 1 row with invalid DepartmentID, it should pick the default DEP_NAME (DEP_ID=null).
Below is how the Query Output should look like-

```
| EMP_ID  |   NAME    | SALARY | DEP_NAME |
|---------|-----------|--------|----------|
|    1    |   Mark    |  6000  |   NYD    |
|    2    |   John    |  4500  |    HR    |
|    3    |   Terry   |  5000  |   NYD    |
|    4    |   Carol   |  15500 | Analyst  |
|    5    |   Lewis   |  18000 |   NYD    |
```

I tried different ways, but still unable to figure out. Please help

```
select 
    emp.EMP_ID, emp.NAME, emp.SALARY, dep.DEP_NAME
from
    employee emp
join department dep on ....
where ....
```

Comment: Your data makes very little sense, having NULL as a value to join on is a bad idea, it's not clear what you mean by valid since employees with a NULL or defined value have a matching row, I would re-think your data model.

Comment: What happens if you have multiple NULL values in `Departments`? And why do you assume I downvoted on your question? Voting is anonymous.

Comment: Regarding Voting part- My Bad, really my Bad. Sorry for that.
Regarding Department table- There will always be only one row with `Dep_Id=null`. But I understand your point. The data that I have presented, it doesn't look really great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit more compactly, you can use two outer joins, one to get valid departments, one to get the default, then use `NVL` or `COALESCE` to choose between them. Lastly collapse row count down to only most desired result by using an analytical function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT emp_id,name,salary, dep_name
  FROM (SELECT emp_id,name,salary,NVL(d.dep_name,def.dep_name) dep_name,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.emp_id ORDER BY d.dep_id) seq
          FROM employee e
               LEFT OUTER JOIN department d ON d.dep_id = e.dep_id
               LEFT OUTER JOIN department def ON def.dep_id IS NULL)
 WHERE seq = 1
```

Because you asked, however, for another version that doesn't use nested query blocks, you could also get the same result with `GROUP BY` and some creative aggregation:

```
 SELECT emp_id,
        MAX(name) name,
        MAX(salary) salary,
        SUBSTR(MAX(DECODE(d.dep_name,NULL,1,2)||NVL(d.dep_name,def.dep_name)),2) dep_name
   FROM employee e
        LEFT OUTER JOIN department d ON d.dep_id = e.dep_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN department def ON def.dep_id IS NULL
 GROUP BY emp_id               
 ORDER BY 1
```

This will work, but, all those semi-arbitrary aggregations and the `decode/substr` trick make this much less desirable than the nested query block and analytic function method above.

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this query. This gives the expected result set. One question - Can this query be modified further to get the same output using single SELECT statement?

Comment: @satyaprakashPanigrahi, this already is a single select statement. Do you mean with a single query block? Yes, using group by. Updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Awesome, the 2nd one does look complicated but I will dissect it & try to implement for my requirement. Thanks once again  :)

Answer (score 1):

Read comments within code:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select e.*,
  3       count(*) over (partition by e.emp_id) cnt
  4     from employee e
  5    )
  6  -- employees with two rows (one with valid, and another invalid DEP_ID)
  7  select t.emp_id, t.name, t.salary, d.dep_name
  8  from temp t join department d on d.dep_id = t.dep_id
  9  where t.cnt = 2
 10  union all
 11  -- employees with only one - invalid - DEP_ID
 12  select t.emp_id, t.name, t.salary, d.dep_name
 13  from temp t cross join department d
 14  where d.dep_id is null
 15    and t.cnt = 1
 16  order by emp_id;

    EMP_ID NAME           SALARY DEP_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Mark             6000 NYD
         2 John             4500 HR
         3 Terry            5000 NYD
         4 Carol           15500 Analyst
         5 Lewis           18000 NYD

SQL>
```

Comment: `count(*) over`  &  `cross join`. Very interesting, gives the desired Output. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can use row_number() analytical function , only thing is what if you have more than 1 row with valid departeement then which one do you want to pick up.

-- untested

```
select * from (
select  emp.EMP_ID, emp.NAME, emp.SALARY, dep.DEP_NAME,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY emp.EMP_ID 
    order by dep.dep_id DESC NULLS LAST)  row_n
from
    employee emp
LEFT outer join department dep on emp.dep_id = dep.dep_id
) where row_n = 1;
```

Comment: I have updated Employee table data & the requirement to bring it much more closer to my actual requirement. Sorry for the confusion.